# как сделать простую кнопку в libGDX?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx

Делаю простенькую игру под андроид на libGDX, и сейчас понадобилось сделать кнопки для управления, до этого тестировал приложение в десктопном варианте, привязав действия к клавишам, попробовал добавить кнопку, но вместо этого просто черно-белая полоса на экране.

```
package com.mygdx.game.Screens;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMap;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.renderers.OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Box2DDebugRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Table;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.ExtendViewport;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.FitViewport;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.Viewport;
import com.mygdx.game.Main;
import com.mygdx.game.Scenes.Hud;
import com.mygdx.game.Sprites.Samurai;
import com.mygdx.game.Tools.B2WorldCreator;
import com.mygdx.game.Tools.WorldContactListener;

public class PlayScreen implements Screen {

    private Main game;

    private TextureAtlas atlas;
    private Stage stage;
    private TextButton button;
    private TextButton.TextButtonStyle textButtonStyle;
    private BitmapFont font;

    private OrthographicCamera gameCam;
    private Viewport gamePort;
    private Hud hud;

    private TmxMapLoader mapLoader;
    private TiledMap map;
    private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;

    private World world;
    private Box2DDebugRenderer b2dr;

    private Samurai player;


    public PlayScreen(Main game) {
        atlas = new TextureAtlas("Fighters/Samurai/Samurai.pack");

        this.game = game;
        gameCam = new OrthographicCamera();
        gamePort = new FitViewport(Main.V_WIDTH / Main.PPM, Main.V_HEIGHT / Main.PPM, gameCam);
        hud = new Hud(game.batch);

        mapLoader = new TmxMapLoader();
        map = mapLoader.load("map/map.tmx");
        renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map, 1 / Main.PPM);
        gameCam.position.set(gamePort.getWorldWidth() / 2, gamePort.getWorldHeight() / 2, 0);

        world = new World(new Vector2(0, -10), true);
        b2dr = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
        // b2dr.setDrawBodies(false);
        player = new Samurai(world, this);
        new B2WorldCreator(world, map);

        world.setContactListener(new WorldContactListener());


        stage = new Stage(gamePort);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

        font = new BitmapFont();
        textButtonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
        textButtonStyle.font = font;
        button = new TextButton("BUTTON", textButtonStyle);


        Table table = new Table();
        table.add(button);
        table.row();
        table.setFillParent(true);
        table.center().center();
        stage.addActor(table);
    }

    public TextureAtlas getAtlas() {
        return atlas;
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {

    }

    public void handleInput(float dt) {
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.SPACE)) {
            player.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0, 2.5f), player.b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);
        }

        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D) && player.b2body.getLinearVelocity().x <= 2) {
            player.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0.1f, 0), player.b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);
        }

        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A) && player.b2body.getLinearVelocity().x >= -2) {
            player.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(-0.1f, 0), player.b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);
        }
    }

    public void update(float dt) {
        handleInput(dt);

        player.update(dt);
        world.step(1/60f, 6, 2);

        gameCam.position.x = player.b2body.getPosition().x;

        gameCam.update();
        renderer.setView(gameCam);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        update(delta);

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        renderer.render();

        b2dr.render(world, gameCam.combined);

        game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(gameCam.combined);

        game.batch.begin();
        player.draw(game.batch);
        game.batch.end();

        stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        stage.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        gamePort.update(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        map.dispose();
        renderer.dispose();
        world.dispose();
        b2dr.dispose();
        hud.dispose();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Добавьте в переменные:**

```libgdx
private Stage stage;
private TextButton button;
private TextButton.TextButtonStyle textButtonStyle;
private BitmapFont font;
private Skin button_skin;
private TextureAtlas button_textureAtlas;
```

`PlayScreen()`:

```libgdx
public PlayScreen(Main game) {
        atlas = new TextureAtlas("Fighters/Samurai/Samurai.pack");

        this.game = game;
        gameCam = new OrthographicCamera();
        gamePort = new FitViewport(Main.V_WIDTH / Main.PPM, Main.V_HEIGHT / Main.PPM, gameCam);
        hud = new Hud(game.batch);

        mapLoader = new TmxMapLoader();
        map = mapLoader.load("map/map.tmx");
        renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map, 1 / Main.PPM);
        gameCam.position.set(gamePort.getWorldWidth() / 2, gamePort.getWorldHeight() / 2, 0);

        world = new World(new Vector2(0, -10), true);
        b2dr = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
        // b2dr.setDrawBodies(false);
        player = new Samurai(world, this);
        new B2WorldCreator(world, map);

        world.setContactListener(new WorldContactListener());
        
        //Кнопка:
        stage = new Stage();
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
        font = new BitmapFont();
        button_skin = new Skin();

        button_textureAtlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("interface/buttons_atlas.atlas"));
        button_skin.addRegions(button_textureAtlas);
        textButtonStyle = new TextButtonStyle();
        textButtonStyle.font = font;
        textButtonStyle.up = button_skin.getDrawable("Button"); //Не нажатая кнопка
        textButtonStyle.down = button_skin.getDrawable("Button_pressed"); //Нажатая кнопка
        button = new TextButton("Play", textButtonStyle);
        button.setSize(button.getWidth() * 16, button.getHeight() * 2); //Размер кнопки, скорее всего надо изменить
        //Место кнопки на экране:
        button.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 - button.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - button.getHeight() * 2);
        stage.addActor(button);

        //Обработчик нажатия кнопки
        button.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
                //ваше действие
            }
        });
        //------
    }
```

`render()`:

```libgdx
@Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        update(delta);

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        renderer.render();

        b2dr.render(world, gameCam.combined);

        game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(gameCam.combined);

        game.batch.begin();
        player.draw(game.batch);
        game.batch.end();

        stage.draw();
    }
```